# What does it mean that a tf.variable is trainable in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

This question came to me when I read the documentation of [global_step](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/global_step).
Here it explicitly declares global_step is not trainable.

> global_step_tensor = tf.Variable(10, trainable=False, name='global_step')
>
> sess = tf.Session()
>
> print('global_step: %s' % tf.train.global_step(sess, global_step_tensor))

From my understanding, trainable means that the value could be changed during sess.run(). I have tried to declare it both trainable and non-trainable and got the same results. So I didn't understand why we need to declare it not trainable.

I read the documentation of [trainable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables) but didn't quite get it.

So my question is:

1. Can non-trainable variable value be changed during sess.run() and vice versa?
2. What is the point that make a variable not trainable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> From my understanding, trainable means that the value could be changed during sess.run()

That is not the definition of a *trainable* variable. **Any** variable can be modified during a `sess.run()` (That's why they are variables and not constants).

The distinction between trainable variables and non-trainable variables is used to let `Optimizer`s know which variables they can act upon.
When defining a `tf.Variable()`, setting `trainable=True` (the default) automatically adds the variable to the `GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` collection.
During training, an optimizer gets the content of that collection via `tf.trainable_variables()` and applies the training to all of them.

The typical example of a non-trainable variable is `global_step`, because its value does change over time (+1 at each training iteration, typically), but you don't want to apply an optimization algorithm to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just to confirm that for this case, whether declare global_step trainable or not should give the same result of the total number of step. The only difference is that how optimal the program will run?

Comment: Declaring it trainable causes an optimizer to see it in `trainable_variables`. I don't know whether this causes problems or not, as I never tried it myself. I suggest you, however, to declare `global_step` via `tf.train.get_or_create_global_step` which automatically declares it non-trainable (or retrieves an existing `global_step` variable in case it was already defined somewhere in your graph)